# Angular - multiple routes for a component with loadChildren?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to have multiple angular routes for a child component and I must use lazy loading (loadChildren).

- /page1/from1 -> MyComponent
- /page2/from2 -> MyComponent
- /page1/from2 -> no match
- /page2/from1 -> no match

As we can see, */page1/from1* and */page2/from2* should show show *MyComponent*, but */page1/from2* must not route to *MyComponent*.

Here's what I've tried:

**The app routing:**

```
const routes: Routes = [
   { path: 'page1', loadChildren: () => import(`./MyComponentModule.module`).then(x => x.MyComponentModule) },
   { path: 'page2', loadChildren: () => import(`./MyComponentModule.module`).then(x => x.MyComponentModule) }
];
```

**The component module routing:**

```
const routes: Routes = [
   { path: 'from1', component: MyComponentModule }, 
   { path: 'from2', component: MyComponentModule }
];
```

**The problem with this solution**

This matches /page1/from2 as well as /page2/from1, which is not what I need. Is there an elegant way to do this?

Comment: if we have page 3 we should just show form 3 ?

Comment: @ArashHatami No, I have planty of pages like this with specific names but those are just example names. I don't want to use any kind of wildcard matching

Comment: Can't you use router parameter ?

Comment: I don't see how I could do that without breaking the lazy loading :-(

Comment: for each page you load specific module ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use router parameters

```
const routes: Routes = [
   { path: 'page/:id', loadChildren: () => import(`./MyComponentModule.module`).then(x => x.MyComponentModule) },
];
```

.

```
const routes: Routes = [
   { path: 'from/:id', component: MyComponentModule }, 
];
```